# decomposition of independent random variables

Tags: random-variable, independence

If X and Y are independent random variables such that X = A + B and Y = C + D? Are the pairs (A, C), (B, C), (A, D), (B, D) also independent? By this I mean whether A and C are independent, B and C are independent and so on.

Comment: Let's see: $(A,C)-(B,C)-(A,D)+(B,D)=(0,0)$ shows those four pairs are linearly dependent.  Can a set of linearly dependent random variables be independent?

Comment: @whuber: I mean whether A and C are independent, B and C are independent and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any further information about $A, B, C, D$, it is not possible to say
anything about their independence.  For example, suppose that

$$\begin{align}
A &= \frac{X+Y}{2}\\
B &= \frac{X-Y}{2}\\
C & = \frac{X+Y}{2} = A\\
D &=  \frac{Y-X}{2} = -B
\end{align}$$

Then, $A$ and $C$ cannot be independent since they are identical and neither
can $B$ and $D$ be independent since their sum is $0$.  In general, 
$B$ and $C$ are not independent, but in special cases, they might be.
For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent *normal* random variables
with identical variance, then $\frac{X+Y}{2}$ and $\frac{X-Y}{2}$ are
independent. In this special case, the pairs $(A,B)$, $(A, D)$, $(B, C)$,
and $(C,D)$ are independent while $(A,C)$ and $(B,D)$ are not.  Other 
choices of $A, B, C, D$ will 
give different results.  So,
as stated earlier, there is not anything concrete that can be said in
the absence of any information about $A,B, C, D$.